# How to align the user control position on webbrowser control in C#

Tags: c#, browser, controls

I have created a web browser control and a form user control. How to align form user control is a center on web browser. Please look above of image.Thanks.

http://i200.photobucket.com/albums/aa41/xuanhung123/Untitled3.png

Comment: Post a screenshot that's bigger than a postage stamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put that in a div and mention styles for div as follows

```
<div class="divUserCtrl">
   <!-- put your control here-->
</div>
```

and in the CSS

```
.divUserCtrl
{
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: In here, I'm using Web browser control and User Control. I'm not using HTML. Thank for your comment.